# OS X boot loader overwritten when Kali linux was installed, stuck with linux

Tags: boot, osx, kali-linux, grub

After dual-booting the Macbook(High Sierra)and installing Kali, I'm only getting prompt with the Kali Linux GRUB boot loader, which lists only one OS(Kali), when booting.

I firstly made another partition on the harddrive of my macbook(2009)
Installed Kali Linux on the free space i made,
and from here after the installation, i was unable to boot to my main OS X.
Even booting from USB is a no-go it seems.(unable to peform the commands)

When booting up the Mac, it prompts with a white screen, with sound, holding the buttons no longer prompt me the apple logo, for recovery or usb.

a few seconds after the white screen appears, it just switches to the GRUB loader. which Kali Linux is only shown.

The main partition with the OS X loaded on it is still intact.
I'd need to remove the 2 latest partition's, and boot into the MAC OS X again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had also the same problem. This is what did to fix the issue:
During startup, press the **Option** key and select the Mac OS partition. Then after you are booted to OS-X, go to **system preferences** then go to **startup disk** and the Mac OS partition. This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure grub2 to be your boot manager, mark OS X as the default OS if you want, that way you can easily switch between OS' as needed.

See https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/189079-grub2-as-the-only-boot-loader-its-possible/

Add a grub entry with:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

then, add:

```
menuentry "Mac OS X" {
set root=(hd0,6)
insmod video
insmod vbe
gfxmode="1280x800x32"
xnu_kernel /mach_kernel rd=disk0s6
if [ /System/Library/Extensions.mkext -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
   xnu_mkext /System/Library/Extensions.mkext
else
   xnu_kextdir /System/Library/Extensions
fi
}
```

Note that you might have to edit the boot entry above because `disk0s6` might not have your root file system, you need to find the right slice.

Then you want to apply the config:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```